# Visual C++ express 10 using too much memory

Tags: visual-c++

I use process explorer (which is a microsoft tool) on windows XP, and often the "physical memory" is being filled at max (3GB) while I use visual C++. At a point, all my programs are slow and are unresponsive, and when it returns to normal, available memory comes back by nearly half ! What is wrong ?

I'm programming some project with Ogre3D, maybe I can deactivate some options in visual, what exactly is it caching that eats that much memory ?

Comment: Which version of VC++? How big is your project? Is VC++ using all the memory (it's rarely cleared 600MB or so for me) or are other programs contributing? Is this happening during a build or in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently MSVC is designed to work on big machines, there are many settings in text editor -> C++ to remove some weight, but my guess is that windows xp + recent microsoft apps don't play nice.